# Python qrcode package - use of ECI

Tags: python, qr-code

I'm programming an automated system which will automatically fill the input fields in universal payment order. This UPO has a QR code field and the QR code has very specific requirements:

- version: 15
- data type: mode byte
- error connection level: M
- use of ECI
- size of module: 0,42333 mm x 0,42333 mm
- size:  32,59676 mm x 32,59667 mm
- minimum resolution: 600 x 600 DPI

is there a python library that provides all of the functionalities? I looked at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode but I'm not sure if ECI is included.

Comment: Hi Rok! I'm also programming the updated UPNs. Did you then find and ECI  4 compatible component?

Comment: I talked with some people and the standard python QR code library should be good!

Comment: Thanks, but which one is the standard QR code library? The one that you linked has no ECI support.  Actually I needed a Delphi QRCode generator, which I have hacked to append `0111 00000100` as a header, which translates to ECI 4 :)

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode this one or you can also use this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/